# Confusion in creation of global variables

Tags: php

How is `$x` and `$y` global variables if they don't have global written before them?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php 
$x = 75;
$y = 25; 

function addition() {
     $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
}

addition();
echo $z;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's how PHP works, maybe. Every variable defined outside of loop, functions, objects are considered as global variable.

Comment: PHP [documentation on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Was this answer not to your satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

Because they are defined in the global namespace.
A variable declared in a function can only be used within that function. You can overrule this by using the `global` operator that looks for the variable in the global name space.

```
function addition() {
     global $x, $y;
     $GLOBALS['z'] = $x + $y;
}
```

However the `$GLOBALS` variable is a place where all globals are stored. Since you define it in that function the `$z` variable is set.

Comment: But its not defined inside that function.

Comment: @FahadUddin odd wording. What he means is that any variable that is not in a function, loop, etc... are global and accessible everywhere.

Comment: No, I skipped the part where he was setting the global variable. My bad for not reading the code properly. I've updated the answer.